# If I add a callback to a 'bind' does it trigger when its bound or everytime it is called?

Tags: jquery, callback, bind

I have the following script:

```
$('#target').bind('click', 
                        function () {
                            $('#target').css({ 'display': 'none' });
                            $('#targetFake').css({ 'display': 'inline-block' });
                        },
                        function () {
                            alert('bind callback'); 
                        });
```

The 'bind callback' alert seems to be triggering everytime that the '#target' element is being clicked instead of only once when the element is being bound. Can I make a callback to verify that the binding is happening once?

Comment: Bro this aint markup this is script, yes this will bind everything indeed. B-) Magic innit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how it should be working: one trigger per click event. The binding happens once per `bind` call; if you accidentally call `bind` multiple times with the same handler you will see the handler triggered multiple times by just one `click`.

However: what are the two functions doing in your [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) call? There is no overload that accepts two functions.

Other alternatives you might be looking for are:

- Calling a function only once on the spot -- just call it directly, you don't need jQuery for that.
- Binding a handler that only gets triggered the *first* time the event happens -- use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) for this purpose.
- Binding a handler normally *and* calling it once on the spot; you can do this with `$(...).bind('click', ...).trigger('click')`.

Comment: Can I make a callback or a function that happens only when the binding happens?

Comment: @WilliamCalleja: You don't need to bind, just call it directly.

Comment: I merely need to make sure that the handler is being bound once to the element because I have reason to beleive that it is happening multiple times.

Comment: @WilliamCalleja: You can simply place an `alert` next to the `bind` call, so that you see an alert each time. Although in 2012 browsers' developer tools can also place breakpoints in Javascript, so simply setting a breakpoint on the `bind` would achieve the goal much more easily.

Comment: My 'two functions' was my attempt at making a callback. That was my bad.